# Bash command to see if any files in dir - test if a directory is empty

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have the following bash script:

```
if ls /Users/david/Desktop/empty > /dev/null
then
    echo 'yes -- files'
else
    echo 'no -- files'
fi
```

How would I modify the top line such that it evaluates true if there are one or more files in the `/Users/david/Desktop/empty` dir?

Comment: Do you want a count of files, files & directories, including/excluding hidden `dot` files/directories?

Comment: @StephenP sure, anything that would tell me if the dir is non-empty.

Comment: I'd suggest revisiting the available answers. There are several good ones (those from mklement0 and anubhava being just as good as my own).

Comment: Note that the question uses the word "files" in the wider sense of _any filesystem items contained_ in the question - i.e., that  a generic _emptiness_  test is desired (inferred from which answer was accepted).

Comment: @David542 — I would like to delete my answer because the globbing solutions are better, but I can't delete it when it's the accepted answer. Could you choose something else as accepted? thx.

Comment: @StephenP sure, all set.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is covered in detail in [BashFAQ #004](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/004). Notably, [use of `ls` for this purpose is an antipattern and should be avoided](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

```
shopt -s dotglob   # if including hidden files is desired
files=( "$dir"/* )
[[ -e $files || -L $files ]] && echo "Directory is not empty"
```

`[[ -e $files ]]` doesn't actually check if the entire array's contents exist; rather, it checks the first name returned -- which handles the case when no files match, wherein the glob expression itself is returned as the sole result.

---

Notably:

- This is **far faster** than invoking `ls`, which requires using `fork()` to spawn a subshell, `execve()` to replace that subshell with `/bin/ls`, the operating system's dynamic linker to load shared libraries used by the `ls` binary, etc, etc. [An exception to this is extremely large directories, of tens of thousands of files -- a case in which `ls` will also be slow; see the `find`-based solution below for those].
- This is **more correct** than invoking `ls`: The list of files returned by globbing is guaranteed to exactly match the literal names of files, whereas `ls` can munge names with hidden characters. If the first entry is a valid filename, `"${files[@]}"` can be safely iterated over with assurance that each returned value will be a name, and there's no need to worry about filesystems with literal newlines in their names inflating the count if the local `ls` implementation does not escape them.

---

That said, an alternative approach is to use `find`, if you have one with the `-empty` extension (available both from GNU find and from modern BSDs including Mac OS):

```
[[ $(find -H "$dir" -maxdepth 0 -type d -empty) ]] || echo "Directory is not empty"
```

...if *any* result is given, the directory is nonempty. While slower than globbing on directories which are not unusually large, this is faster than *either* `ls` or globbing for extremely large directories not present in the direntry cache, as it can return results without a full scan.

Answer (score 10):

**Robust pure Bash** solutions:

<sup>For background on ***why* a pure Bash solution with globbing is superior to using `ls`**, see **[Charles Duffy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35282784/45375)**, which also contains a **`find`-based alternative**, which is **much faster and less memory-intensive with *large* directories**.[1]

Also consider **anubhava's equally fast and memory-efficient [`stat`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35284977/45375)**, which, however, requires distinct syntax forms on Linux and BSD/OSX.</sup>

<sup>*Updated* to a simpler solution, gratefully adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43402951/45375).</sup>

```
# EXCLUDING hidden files and folders - note the *quoted* use of glob '*'
if compgen -G '*' >/dev/null; then
  echo 'not empty'
else
  echo 'empty, but may have hidden files/dirs.'
fi
```

- `compgen -G` is normally used for tab completion, but it is useful in this case as well:

  - Note that `compgen -G` does its *own* globbing, so you must pass it the glob (filename pattern) *in quotes* for it to output all matches. In this particular case, even passing an *unquoted* pattern up front would work, but the difference is worth nothing.
  - if nothing matches, `compgen -G` *always* produces *no* output  (irrespective of the state of the `nullglob` option), and it indicates via its exit code whether at least 1 match was found, which is what the conditional takes advantage of (while suppressing any stdout output with `>/dev/null`).

```
# INCLUDING hidden files and folders - note the *unquoted* use of glob *
if (shopt -s dotglob; compgen -G * >/dev/null); then
  echo 'not empty'
else
  echo 'completely empty'
fi
```

- `compgen -G` *never* matches *hidden* items (irrespective of the state of the `dotglob` option), so a workaround is needed to find hidden items too:

  - `(...)` creates a subshell for the conditional; that is, the commands executed in the subshell don't affect the current shell's environment, which allows us to set the `dotglob` option in a localized way.
  - `shopt -s dotglob` causes `*` to match hidden items too (except for `.` and `..`).
  - `compgen -G *` with *unquoted* `*`, thanks to *up-front* expansion by the shell, is either passed at least one filename, whether hidden or not (additional filenames are ignored) or the empty string, if neither hidden nor non-hidden items exists. In the former case the exit code is `0` (signaling success and therefore a nonempty directory), in the later `1` (signaling a truly empty directory).

---

<sup>[1]
This answer originally *falsely* claimed to offer a Bash-only solution that is efficient with large directories, based on the following approach: `(shopt -s nullglob dotglob; for f in "$dir"/*; do exit 0; done; exit 1)`.
This is NOT more efficient, because, internally, Bash *still* collects all matches in an array first before entering the loop - in other words: `for *` is *not* evaluated lazily.</sup>

Comment: This is an excellent answer and so is the answer from @CharlesDuffy ++ to both the answers. I always learn something by reading these great solutions. However it is strange that OP has marked a supposedly erroneous answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution based on `stat` command that can return **number of hard links** if run against a directory (or link to a directory). It starts incrementing *number of hard links* from 3 as first two are `.` and `..` entries thus subtracting `2` from this number gives as actual number of entries in the given directory (this includes symlinks as well).

So putting it all together:

```
(( ($(stat -Lc '%h' "$dir") - 2) > 0)) && echo 'not empty' || echo 'empty'
```

As per `man stat` options used are:

```
%h     number of hard links
-L     --dereference, follow links
```

**EDIT:** To make it BSD/OSX compatible use:

```
(( ($(stat -Lf '%l' "$dir") - 2) > 0)) && echo 'not empty' || echo 'empty'
```

Comment: Requires GNU stat, but a very good choice -- should be just as fast as `find -empty` in large directories.

Comment: This is interesting, under Linux Mint 17.1, using stat (GNU coreutils) 8.21, your _code_ does not work for me if `$dir` only contains _files_ and no _directories_, while mklement0's _code_ works in OS X when `$dir` contains only _files_ and or _directories_. I have too much respect for you to down vote just because it doesn't work in my test case however IMO this really doesn't answer the OP's question since he did say "any files in dir" when the _code_ can conditionally fail if it's only _files_ and no _directories_ in `$dir`.  Or am I totally missing something here?

Comment: Thanks for your important comment, it appears `stat` behaves differently on different filesystems. I'm on OSX where it identifies any files/directories/links in the given sub-directory. Will try to get access to a Linux host to test further.