# Check if folder contains glob

Tags: bash, macos, shell

On my Mac I am trying to figure out a way to check a mounted volume to a server to see if the directory receives a log file through a shell script that will be used in `launchd` set to a time interval.

From my searches and historically I've used:

```
$DIR="/path/to/file"
THEFILES=(`find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.log"`)
if [ ${#THEFILES[@]} -gt 0 ]; then 
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "nothing"
fi
```

If the shell script is placed inside that particular directory and the files are present.  However, when I move the script outside of that directory and try:

```
THEFILES=(`find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.log"`)
cd $DIR
if [ ${#THEFILES[@]} -gt 0 ]; then 
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "nothing"
fi
```

I get a constant return of `nothing`.  I thought it might be in regards to the depth so I changed `-maxdepth 1` to `-maxdepth 0` but I still get `nothing`.  Through searching I ran across "[Check whether a certain file type/extension exists in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3856879/1952287)" and tried:

```
THEFILES=$(ls "$DIR/.log" 2> /dev/null | wc -l)
echo $THEFILES
```

but I'm returned a constant `0`.  When I searched further I ran across "[Checking from shell script if a directory contains files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/91558/1952287)" and tried a variation using `find` with:

```
THEFILES=$(find "$DIR" -type f -regex '*.log')
cd $DIR
if [ ${#THEFILES[@]} -gt 0 ]; then 
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "nothing"
fi
```

with a blank return.  When I try:

```
if [ -n "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; then
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "nothing"
fi
```

I get a blank terminal returned.  On this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17902999/1952287) I dont have `prune` or `shopt` on my Mac.  So how I can I check a mounted server's directory to see if a particular file with a specific extension exists that will not give a false return from hidden files?

### EDIT:

Per comment I tried removing the depth with:

```
THEFILES=$(find ./ -name "*.log")
```

but I get a blank return but if I drop a `.log` file in there it runs but I don't understand why else isn't returning `nothing` unless it's considering the hidden files.  Thanks to [l'L'l](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499581/lll) I learned `-prune` was in `find`'s utility but when I try:

```
if [ -n "$(find $DIR -prune -empty -type d)" ]; then
```

I get a constant return of `nothing` when there is a LOG file present.

Comment: You are limiting how far the command traverses using `-maxdepth`; it sounds like this might be the issue. Also, `prune` is included in Mac's `find` utility...

Comment: This `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.log` searching from the _current directory_ (where the script is). If you move it outside, of course, it will not work. Use full path name, e.g. `find /full/path/name/to/dir -maxdepth.... etc`

Comment: Maybe try like this `find "$DIR" -name  "*.log" | wc -l`. Many of your commands are suppressing the output, or setup in a way that is not going to return anything.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what you're looking for. You have the directory and you just want to see if `*.log` is present in that directory?

Comment: @miken32 that is correct.  In 5 minute intervals through an app I want to check whenever a Log file is present in the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your proposed answer is really close to working!

I didn't use the `-maxdepth` option, if it is important to you to only check the files under `$DIR` but not its subdirectories, feel free to add `-maxdepth 1` to any call to `find`.

Use lowercase variables as pointed by *mklement0* to avoid conflicts with environment variables.

## Answer 1

You set `dir`, but use `./` instead...

```
dir="/path/to/dir"
# Create an array of filenames
files=( $(find "$dir" -name "*.log") )
if [ ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ]; then # if the length of the array is more than 0
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "nothing"
```

## Answer 2

You use `cd $dir` after running find...

```
dir="path/to/dir"
cd "$dir"
files=( $(find -name "*.log") )
if [ ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "nothing"
fi
```

## Answer 3

you forgot a '*' before the '.log'... Have a look a the documentation for [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)

```
dir="/path/to/dir"
# print all the files in "$DIR" that end with ".log"
# and count the number of lines
nbfiles=$(ls "$dir/"*.log 2> /dev/null | wc -l) # nbfiles is an integer
if [ $nbfiles -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "nothing
fi
```

## Answer 4

The macOS man page of [`find`](https://ss64.com/osx/find.html) suggests that regex uses Basic Regular Expressions by default:

> -E
>
> Interpret regular expressions followed by -regex and -iregex
>          options as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than
>          basic regular expressions (BRE's).

You are missing a `.` before the `*` ; the `cd $dir` is not necessary since you pass `$dir` as an argument to find ; and you don't store the output of `find` in an array, so you can't check the length of the array.

```
# The output of find is stored as a string
files=$(find "/path/to/dir" -type f -regex '.*\.log')
if [ -n "$files" ]; then # Test that the string $files is not empty
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "nothing"
fi
```

Comment: this is a summary of corrections, not an answer.  why not just fix the answers?

Answer (score 2):

The Bash builtin `compgen` "displays possible completions based on the options" and is [typically used for autocomplete scripts](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/tabexpansion.html), but can be used for this purpose also. By default it outputs the completion list, so redirect it to `/dev/null`.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=/some/log/dir
if compgen -G "$dir/*.log" > /dev/null; then
    # do stuff
fi
```

Comment: Interesting approach never heard or used `compgen ` before, +1 for the answer.

Comment: That's a neat trick - I've taken the liberty to adapt it for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35282925/45375), in the context of detecting whether a directory is empty or not (a workaround is needed to detect _hidden_ items).